# How to add a json value in multiple lines

Tags: java, json

I am trying to add a json value break up in multiple lines as below

```
{"sometext": "line1
           line2
           line3"
            
}
```

Getting the below error while parsing

```
Parse error on line
...      {"sometext": "line1             
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: What you are looking for is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532468/1531124 ... you need to use the `\n` to slice lines for example.

Comment: Meaning: the json you are showing us is simply invalid.